# How to get radio button output in Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

Here is the code which i wrote to have radio button with its option and other widget to see on the gui face...but it is not running. i mean when there is radio button code its not showing on the gui face.

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

class Application:
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.top=top
        # initializer for gui
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):
        var="Application"
        helv16=tkFont.Font(self.top,family="Helvetica",size=16,slant="italic")
        label1=Label(self.top,text=var,font=helv16,bd=5,fg='#2ddef9',bg='#aaecaa',relief=RIDGE,padx=17,pady=4,justify="center")
        label1.pack(side=TOP)

        label2=Label(self.top,text='Proxy City', bd=3,fg='red',bg='#FFFFFF',relief=GROOVE,padx=18,pady=4,justify="center")
        label2.grid(row=2, column=1)
        # setting default proxy city to Bangalore
        v=IntVar()
        # initiallize to Bangalore
        v.set(1)

        list_city=[("Bangalore", 1), ("Chennai", 2), ("USA", 3), ("Chaina", 4)]
        for city, num in list_city:
            #print city, num
            radiobttn=Radiobutton(self.top, text=city, padx=10,pady=5, variable=v, value=num,command=sel, bd=3,fg='red',bg='#FFFFFF',relief=GROOVE)
        radiobttn.pack(anchor='w')

        label3=Label(self.top,text='Add URL', bd=3,fg='red',bg='#FFFFFF',relief=GROOVE,padx=17,pady=4,justify="center")
        entry3=Entry(self.top,relief=SUNKEN,justify=CENTER,bd=3,fg='#0000FF',font='arial')

        label3.grid(row=3, column=0)
        entry3.grid(row=3, column=1)

        label3=Label(self.top,text='Add URL', bd=3,fg='red',bg='#FFFFFF',relief=GROOVE,padx=17,pady=4,justify="center")
        entry3=Entry(self.top,relief=SUNKEN,justify=CENTER,bd=3,fg='#0000FF',font='arial')
        label3.grid(row=4, column=0)
        entry3.grid(row=4, column=1)

    def sel():
        selection = "You selected the option " + str(v.get())
        label.config(text = selection)


def main():

    top=Tk()
    top.geometry("680x600+400+240")
    top.title("Application")
    Application(top)
    top.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: you found any solution?

Comment: yes ...i got solution and thanks for ur help...one more things i m new here as well as in python ...so it took time to thanks to u ..thank u ..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There were many instances where you haven't used variables in the class scope but only in the method's scope but I fixed them

Your fixed code would look like:

```
from Tkinter import *
import tkFont

class Application:
    def __init__(self, top):
        self.top=top
        # initializer for gui
        self.gui()

    def gui(self):
        var="Application"
        helv16=tkFont.Font(self.top,family="Helvetica",size=16,slant="italic")
        self.label1=Label(self.top,text=var,font=helv16,bd=5,fg='#2ddef9',bg='#aaecaa',relief=RIDGE,padx=17,pady=4,justify="center")
        self.label1.pack(side=TOP)

        label2=Label(self.top,text='Proxy City', bd=3,fg='red',bg='#FFFFFF',relief=GROOVE,padx=18,pady=4,justify="center").pack()
        # setting default proxy city to Bangalore
        self.v=IntVar()
        # initiallize to Bangalore
        self.v.set(1)


        list_city=[("Bangalore", 1), ("Chennai", 2), ("USA", 3), ("Chaina", 4)]
        for city, num in list_city:
            #print city, num
            Radiobutton(self.top, text=city, padx=10,pady=5, variable=self.v, value=num,command=self.sel, bd=3,fg='red',bg='#FFFFFF',relief=GROOVE).pack(anchor='w')

        label3=Label(self.top,text='Add URL', bd=3,fg='red',bg='#FFFFFF',relief=GROOVE,padx=17,pady=4,justify="center").pack()
        entry3=Entry(self.top,relief=SUNKEN,justify=CENTER,bd=3,fg='#0000FF',font='arial').pack()

    def sel(self):
        selection = "You selected the option " + str(self.v.get())
        self.label1.config(text = selection)


def main():
    top=Tk()
    top.geometry("680x600+400+240")
    top.title("Application")
    Application(top)
    top.mainloop()

if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

*Note : I never understood that part of your code where you are overwriting an existing label!* **This is bad practice and should not be followed**

```
label3=Label(self.top,text='Add URL', bd=3,fg='red',bg='#FFFFFF',relief=GROOVE,padx=17,pady=4,justify="center")
entry3=Entry(self.top,relief=SUNKEN,justify=CENTER,bd=3,fg='#0000FF',font='arial')

label3.grid(row=3, column=0)
entry3.grid(row=3, column=1)

label3=Label(self.top,text='Add URL', bd=3,fg='red',bg='#FFFFFF',relief=GROOVE,padx=17,pady=4,justify="center")
entry3=Entry(self.top,relief=SUNKEN,justify=CENTER,bd=3,fg='#0000FF',font='arial')
label3.grid(row=4, column=0)
entry3.grid(row=4, column=1)
```

As mentioned by [@BryanOakley](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19953838/how-to-get-radio-button-output-in-tkinter/19956022?noredirect=1#comment43837305_19956022) You can use both the `pack` and `grid` methods inside one mainloop but you can't use both for widgets that share the same parent.

Comment: _"you cannot use both pack and grid methods inside one mainloop"_ is a false statement. You absolutely can and should use both. The only thing you cannot do is use both for widgets that share the same parent.